# Calling Jquery for Streaming API's into Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have been following this [guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq_TnjU0q48) to Integrate Salesforce using the Streaming API, but I keep get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'configure' of undefined OpenPriorityPosition?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1:50

I have uploaded the jquery files as a static zip file resource within salesforce and named it jQueryCometD. The only files in the folder are the four files listed above. The code for the page is listed below:

```
<apex:page >
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.cometd}"/>
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.json2_js}"/>
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery_cometd}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Connect to the CometD endpoint
           configuration = {url:'https://'+window.location.hostname+'/cometd/26.0/',
                            requestHeaders: {
                                "Authorization": "OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}"
                            },
                            appendMessageTypeToURL : false
                           };
           $.cometd.configure(configuration); 
           $.cometd.handshake();

           // Subscribe to a topic.
           // JSON-encoded update will be returned in the callback               
           //TODO #1: Specify the pushtopic.
           $.cometd.subscribe('/topic/openPriorityPosition', function(message) {
               // Message is a JSON-encoded update passed in the callback
               var position = message.data.sobject;
               $('[id*=messages]}').append(
                    '<br/>' + 'Name: ' + (position.Name) +
                    '<br/>' + 'Location: ' + (position.Location__c) + 

                    //TODO #2: Within the () put a reference to the status of the position
                    '<br/>' + 'Status: ' + (position.Status__c) + 
                    //TODO #3: Within the () put a reference to the priority of the position
                    '<br/>' + 'Priority: ' + (position.Priority__c) + 
                    '<hr/>');
            });
        });
   })(jQuery)
  </script>
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Positions" subtitle="New or Modified High/Critical Priority     Positions"/>
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Notifications" />
              <apex:outputPanel id="messages" layout="block" />
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This is the same code that they used in the Dreamforce class this was listed in, so I don't believe there is problem with the code since there instance rendered fine. I believe there is something wrong were my Salesforce instance isn't calling the API or accessing jQuery properly. If someone could help  me out, that would be great. I have tried using jQuery with other examples as well and none of them see to be working. I can obtain the push notifications in the workbench, but nothing renders when I try and add it to a visualforce page.

Comment: is this outputting the correct URL?   {url:'https://'+window.location.hostname+'/cometd/26.0/'

Comment: How do I know if it is outputting the right URL?

Comment: i dunno.  but the error says its with the "configuration" and your error message has "core.apexpages.devmode.url=1:50" which look to be a url parameter.  Do a quick console.log('https://'+window.location.hostname+'/cometd/26.0/') to make sure it looks legit

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same code which you have and it worked fine for me. I can think of 2 possible reasons.

1) Did you zip and upload the statis resources. I just uploaded the files individually.

2)
Did you configure your push topic correctly. You can use https://workbench.developerforce.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `<apex:includeScript>` lines to reference the `jQueryCometD` static resource:

```
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryCometD, 'jquery.js')}"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryCometD, 'cometd.js')}"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryCometD, 'json2.js')}"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryCometD, 'jquery_cometd.js')}"/>
```

Note - you may have to change the filenames to match your zip.

Not certain this is the only issue, but that would certainly stop the example from working.

Comment: On my first try, I changed the includeScript lines to reference exactly what you have above and that came back with a failing 404 error so I changed it to what I have now in my example.